# Problems creating table from data in long format

Tags: r

I'll describe my data:

1. First column are `corine_values`, going from 1 to 50.
2. Second column are `bird_names`, there are 70 different bird_names, each `corine_value` has several `bird_names`.
3. Third column contains the `sex` of the `bird_name`.
4. Fourth column contains a V1-value (`measurement`) that belongs to the category described by the first three columns.

I want to create a table where the the row names are the bird_names. First all the females in alphabetical order, followed by the males in alphabetical order. The column names should be the `corine_values`, from small to big. The data in the table should be the corresponding V1-values.

I've been trying some things, but to be honest I'm just starting with R and I don't really have a clue how to do it. I can sort the data, but not on multiple levels (like alphabetical and sex combined). I'm exporting everything to Excel now and doing it manually, which is very time-consuming.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please consider visiting [How to Ask section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also generate a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)...

Comment: Thank you. I wanted to include an example of my data, but i can't post a picture and I don't find any other way to add data to my question. I can't realy post code because I don't know what commands to use, I did some research but I fail to accurately describy my problem. Long to wide format is the closest i get.

Comment: The tags you were using are not appropritate for this question. Please review [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)